# MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent is not returning data to onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-camera

I have single-activity app and if I want to open Camera using Intent and then just hitting back button will not return me back to my app, instead it will minimize app window and I have to restart app completely in order to get into my app again.

Is there any workaround which will properly close this custom Activity and return me to the place where I called this intent?

Opening Camera:

```
val tempFile = createImageFile()
photoPath = tempFile.absolutePath
photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(a, app.packageName + ".fileprovider", tempFile)

val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
if (intent.resolveActivity(a.packageManager) != null) {
   startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Opening Gallery:

```
private val mimeTypes = arrayOf("application/pdf", "image/*")
private val intentType = "*/*"
private val intentCategory = "android.intent.category.OPENABLE"

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).also {
            it.type = intentType
            it.addCategory(intentCategory)
            it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
        }
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Checked Gallery intent and data from Gallery is returned and passed from `MainActivity` `onActivityResult` to current `Fragment` `onActivityResult` through super call, but for some reason if I start Intent with `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, this intent will never arrive to my Fragment `onActivityResult` and instead it will force to recreate entire Activity.

I can see `onActivtyResult` log inside `MainActivity`, but it is never passed to `Fragment` through super call. This seems to be some Android bug because I had this solution working for past 2 years without any issues until now.

Comment: try using registerForActivityResult launcher as startActivityForResult is deprecated. So, that might be causing the problem

Comment: While I agree that `registerForActivityResult` is the way to go for any modern code, the old and deprecated `startActivityForResult` is still working as far as I know, so it would be a rare regression if it started causing this issue.

Comment: Yeah im using startActivityForResult for years now and its working correctly in other apps. This is some system issue and I cant find any reason why it is happening. My activity is randomly recreating, it is killing all fragments in stack in a process so I cant properly return from Gallery or Camera with my picked photo. It looks like it will kill my Activity before entering to Gallery/Camera and while result is returned, system is recreating that activity, which will wipe out every single Fragment in stack.

Comment: Lesson one: Android OS can kill your activity at any moment if Android OS thinks its good to do do. It often does so when the Camera app is on top of your activity. You have to use onSaveInstanceState to save the state of your activity so you can recreate it later.

Comment: And how do I save entire backstack of my Fragments so if Activity is recreated, It will have all data with previous state? Especially if this CameraFragment is part of backstack which has 4 fragments behind it (Tab3 fragment -> Fragment 1- > Fragment2 -> Fragment3 -> Fragment4(CameraFragment). When default fragment inside onCreate is Tab1 fragment which is completely different flow of screens. I cant recreate that state.